# Use of `this` in operators

Tags: c++

I have something like this:

```
CLASS CLASS::operator|(CLASS& right) {
    return binop(*((CLASS*) this), right, OP_OR);
}
```

CLASS is just some class. 
binop's prototype is

`CLASS binop(CLASS& left, CLASS& right, OP op);`

This all works fine and compiles using Visual C++ 2010 but fails in g++ with an error:

```
someheader.h: In member function 'void CLASS::set(int64_t)':
someheader.h:469:29: error: no match for 'operator|' in '*(CLASS*)this | CLASS(bit)'
someheader.h:469:29: note: candidate is:
someheader.h:376:1: note: CLASS CLASS::operator|(CLASS&)
someheader.h:376:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'CLASS' to 'CLASS&'
```

Now, I'm having problems just passing the current object (*this) as some parameter, so I explicitly cast out it to remove the `const` qualifier on the pointer, which works fine and seems to trick the Visual C++ compiler to accept it as a normal pointer. g++ doesn't seem to like this. If I remove the cast, it still give me an error since `this` is const-qualified. What I do with the left- and right-hand size of the operators requires that both are mutable.

From what I can gather, it seems that there's an issue with me passing some object and converting it to a reference in the function call... Which doesn't make much sense to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's with the funky `*((CLASS *) this)` if the function is a member of CLASS?

Comment: Like I said, the compiler didn't like it when I just used `*this`, so I did the cast to make it happy.

Comment: Oh, it shouldn't have to be that way. Perhaps your `set` function would be worth a look since it's where the error is. Actually, is there a problem with `CLASS& right` being `const CLASS& right`?

Comment: The error message clearly shows where it's erroring, and that's when I use `operator|`. I have the operator implementation listed; the left and right hand size should NOT be `const`-qualified.

Comment: Why is binop using non-const references?  Does it actually modify the arguments?

Comment: Yes, I need both objects to be mutable.

Comment: @Pochi, Do _not_ use a C-cast to remove 'const'.  _That_ is a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio violates the standard here.

Your right-hand argument is a temporary, and according to the rules of C++, a temporary cannot match a non-const reference.

Comment: The temporary is supposed to match as a reference in the callee. Is.. that what you're saying -- that I should create the object in a separate line first? I'm just curious, but is there any chance you can reference where in the standard it says this?

Comment: Well, I guess that fixed it... Thanks!

Comment: a temporrary cannot bind to a non const reference.  MSVC even tells you it's breaking that rule when it compiles.  Look at the warnings.

Comment: a temporrary cannot bind to a non const reference.  MSVC even tells you it's breaking that rule when it compiles.  Look at the warnings.

Comment: @MooingDuck: There are no warnings. If there were I wouldn't have been in such a position.

Comment: @pochi wait, really?  I know I've seen it.  Crank the warning level up to 4 in the project properties, it should show up then.

Comment: @pochi: Section 8.5.3p5 requires binding a reference to an lvalue unless either the reference is an rvalue reference or the reference is `const`.  A temporary isn't an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `operator|` something like this:

```
int bit = 0x02;
CLASS result = *this | (CLASS)bit;
```

Your operator takes a reference.

```
CLASS CLASS::operator| (CLASS &right);
```

To solve this for GCC, I found that either calling it like this:

```
CLASS result = *this | (CLASS &)bit;
```

or defining the operator like this:

```
CLASS CLASS::operator| (CLASS &&right); //C++11
```

Both caused it to return the correct result back. I can't guarantee one or the other is *the* solution though.

Comment: bboth of those are wrong, as they modify 'right' instead of a copy of right.

Comment: @MooingDuck, from what I saw, that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: I misread the second one, that should work fine.  And I had thought bit was a CLASS, which would have made the code drastically different.  This answer is a good one.